# Excel 2003: Programmatic sort of sheet in different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

From the current workbook, I want to open a sheet in the source workbook, turn off any filtering that may be present, sort by one column, then another, then another.  Am getting 1004 and other errors.  This needs to run on 2003.  Any help will be appreciated!

```
Dim WB As Workbook, WasWBOpen As Boolean, srcfile As String, srcpath As String,    
onecol as integer, twocol as integer, thrcol as integer

srcpath = "blahblah"
srcfile = "blah.xls"

On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks(srcfile)
WasWBOpen = True
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(srcpath & srcfile, UpdateLinks:=False)
WasWBOpen = False
End If

'code before this opens source wkbook

lstrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Row - 1 + Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
lstcol = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Column - 1 + Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count

onecol=3
twocol=5
thrcol=8

With WB.Sheets("Sheet1")

.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("1:1").AutoFilter
'Here's where error occurs--
.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lstrow, lstcol)).Sort _
    Key1:=Columns(onecol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Key2:=Columns(twocol), Order2:=xlAscending, _
    Key3:=Columns(thrcol), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End With

If WasWBOpen = False Then
WB.Close
End If
```

Comment: Which line in particular are you getting the 1004?

Comment: The line with the "Here's where..." comment

Comment: haha, totally missed that. I don't see where you are giving oneCol, twocol, thrcol any data. Where is that code?

Comment: I was adding that while you were typing I think lol; to be clear, that was in my code already in Excel--I'm still looking for help on this! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lstrow, lstcol)).Sort _
```

is better written as:

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lstrow, lstcol)).Sort _
```

Comment: Did you also qualify the following 'Columns' references ?

Comment: ahh good eyes, Tim. It is good to point out the reason to use the .Cells there is because the Cells without the dot infers the currently active sheet. I believe that's what you were saying, but just wanted to explicitly state it.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you can only sort the active worksheet.  Try adding `.Activate` after `WB.Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Information about the last sort is stored against the worksheet.  I sometimes suspect this is the problem rather than the sheet to be sorted not being active.  But `.Activate` has always worked for me and so I have never investigated further.

**Extra information**

I had assumed it was the `Sort` that generated the error but it is the `AutoFilter`.

I can generate a 1004 error by leaving row 1 empty.

What purpose does the `AutoFilter` statement serve?  With `AutoFilterMode = False` I would expect it to return `Nothing`.  Why not delete this statement?

I am also concerned about the range you are sorting.  You are subtracting the number of unused rows at the top and unused columns on the left to calculate lstrow and lstcol but then including those unused rows and columns in the sort.  The result is that rows at the bottom and columns on the right would not be sorted.

If have not got any unused rows at the top and unused columns on the left, this will not matter but you need to decide which range you want to sort.

**Extra information 2**

This section was added after I discovered a fourth way of breaking the original code.  The following code appears to be bomb-proof.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestSort2()

Dim WB As Workbook, WasWBOpen As Boolean, srcfile As String, srcpath As String
Dim onecol As Integer, twocol As Integer, thrcol As Integer

' Undeclared or new variables

Dim InxWB As Long
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim lstcol As Long
Dim srcpathfile As String

' Report the name of the active workbook
Debug.Print "Original active workbook " & ActiveWorkbook.Name

' I created two workbooks named "Failed sort 1.xls" and "Failed sort 2.xls".
' Both are in the same directory. "Failed sort 1.xls" contains this macro.
' "Failed sort 2.xls" contains the data.
srcpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
srcfile = "Failed sort 2.xls"

srcpathfile = srcpath & "\" & srcfile

WasWBOpen = False
' Check the open workbook for srcfile
For InxWB = 1 To Workbooks.Count
  If Workbooks(InxWB).Name = srcfile Then
    ' Required workbook already open
    Set WB = Workbooks(InxWB)
    WB.Activate                     ' Activate it
    WasWBOpen = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next
If Not WasWBOpen Then
  ' Files was not open
  If Dir(srcpathfile) <> "" Then
    ' File exists
    ' Do you need UpdateLinks:=False?  If there are links
    ' with the sort be affected if they are not updated? 
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(srcpathfile, UpdateLinks:=False)
  Else
    ' File does not exist
    Call MsgBox(srcpathfile & " does not exist", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If
End If

' WB is now the active workbook whether it was open before or not
Debug.Print "Final active workbook " & ActiveWorkbook.Name      ' Confirm

With Sheets("Sheet1")
  .Activate
  .AutoFilterMode = False

  ' Get the last used row and cell of the worksheet
  lstrow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  lstcol = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

  onecol = 3
  twocol = 5
  thrcol = 8

  If onecol > lstcol Or twocol > lstcol Or thrcol > lstcol Then
    Call MsgBox("The sort range does include the sort columns", vbOKOnly)
    If Not WasWBOpen Then
      Close
    End If
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lstrow, lstcol)).Sort _
        Key1:=Columns(onecol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Key2:=Columns(twocol), Order2:=xlAscending, _
        Key3:=Columns(thrcol), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With

If Not WasWBOpen Then
  Close
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: I added that but I get the same error at the same line.  Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: I have done some more experimentation and have added extra information to report the results.

Comment: I got rid of the Autofilter bits but I still get the 1004, with the same highlight. I appreciate your advice; you really thought this through.  I supressed the lstrow and lstcol formulae and just hard-coded the right numbers to rule that out. Still getting the error!?

Comment: I can get three different versions of the 1004 error depending on what errors I make.  The versions are: "Application-defined or object error", "The sort reference is not valid. ..." and "The command could not be completed with the range specified".  Which one do you get?  Please step through the macro with F8, checking values.  When the run-time error screen is displayed, please click Debug so you can tell which statement is throwing the error.

Comment: I have discovered a fifth way of breaking your code. If the workbook containing the data is open but is not active, your code fails because you do not activate it. I have included an amended version of your code in my answer. I have made the minimum changes necessary to defeat the four failures I reported and one that justnS and Tim Williams reported.

Comment: "In my experience you can only sort the active worksheet." - as that isn't the case suggest that your post should be edited as not to confuse further readers. It is very rare that `Select` or `Activate` is needed in VBA.

Comment: For the final version, I carefully removed all the leading dots in the sort because, if I am relying on the target worksheet being active, I like it to be obvious. However, originally the dots were there. I save the data workbook with the cursor in a different worksheet and without activate the sort fails. I do not know if this is an Excel 2003 problem that has been fixed in Excel 2007 or if I am making some subtle error that activate covers up. If it is my error, I wish I could discover what it is. In the meantime, the advice that activate will sometimes fix a sort is, I think, worth giving.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can make a stab at is perhaps your selection does not include columns 3, 5 or 8. What are the values of `lstrow` and `lstcol` before the error?

Comment: lstrow and lstcol are integer numbers; I msgbox-ed them to verify